# Wordpress alpha order by last name, first name

Tags: php, wordpress

Got a bit of an issue i'm trying to get solved and haven't been able to get a query that reflects what I want.

Basically I have a long list of bio's to click on, they are sorted by last_name, which is an advanced custom field, however, there are a few situations where there are people with the same last name, and so it then needs to order them by their first name as well (acf field called first_name).

Currently the query is

```
$peopleQuery = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => array('lawyer'),
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby' => array('meta_value' => 'ASC'),
      'meta_key' => 'last_name'
    ));
```

And i've tried ordering like this

```
'orderby' => array(
    'last_name' => 'ASC',
    'first_name' => 'ASC'
)
```

but to no change. Has anybody ever done this successfully? Is there a way to maybe sort the query how i have it now but then use PHP to order those cases? Any tips or help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm does this work then?:

```
$peopleQuery = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => array('lawyer'),
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'meta_query' => array(
          array(
              'key' => 'last_name',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value',
              'order'    => ASC
          ),
          array(
              'key' => 'first_name',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value',
              'order'    => ASC
          ),
       ),
    );
```

[this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109849/order-by-desc-asc-in-custom-wp-query) also seems to do manually it via filters which seems to work pre 4.0

Comment: unfortunately no that doesn't work. for example, the names: `james brown`, `michelle brown` and dude brown appear in that order, so `dude brown` would need to be first.

Comment: What WP version are you using. Using multiple `orderby` values wasn't implemented correctly prior to 4.0

Comment: edited to use meta_query to order them. not sure if it'll work but give that a try

Comment: Luke's also right in that pre 4.0 orderby mulitple values wasn't working right. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/

Comment: Nope, your updated version puts more emphasis on the first name. I'm running the newest version